What should my query look like for a Power Query Table column to provide an average of values in a mother column that match?
I have a table in power query "MASTER_Global Game Table" which has multiple columns in it. I have added an additional column which I would like to provide an average of another column for all rows that have matching values in another column. So....



event
score
average




ev1
33



ev1
40



ev1
23



ev2
90



ev2
80



ev2
34



ev3
76



ev3
86




In the example above I would like to have the average column show the average score for the event in that row.
The result for this example would mean that "32" would appear in each of the ev1 rows under average.

You could try getting group averages first and joining with it:
let 
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  groupedByEvent = Table.Group(Source, {"event"}, {{"Avg", each List.Average([score]), type any}}),
  mergedWithGrouped = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"event"}, groupedByEvent, {"event"}, "EventAverage", JoinKind.Inner),
  expandedEventAverage = Table.ExpandTableColumn(mergedWithGrouped, "EventAverage", {"Avg"}, {"Avg"}) 
 in
    expandedEventAverage



Right click the event column and use Group By

Then click on the arrow atop the data column and expand the score column into rows

